# Issue with taking a picture by using opencv?

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am trying to take a picture from a camera frame using OpenCV in android and save it to the disk. But for some reason when i click on the button, nothing happens. I am really clueless as how I should go about it.

```
 b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             Imgcodecs.imwrite("test.jpg",mrgba);

             }
        });


  @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

        mrgba = inputFrame.rgba();

        // Imgproc.cvtColor(mrgba,mgray,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
       // Imgproc.Canny(mgray,mcanny,50,150);
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
        float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
        float h = mrgba.cols();
        float w = mrgba.rows();


        int centerx = (int) (mrgba.width()*0.5);
        int  centery = (int) (mrgba.height() * 0.5);
        Rect rect = new Rect(centerx,centery,100,100);

        Imgproc.circle(mrgba,new Point(centerx,centery),200,new Scalar(255,0,0),10);
        //Imgproc.resize(mrgba,mrgba,new Size(mrgba.width()*0.3,mrgba.height()*0.3));

        return mrgba;
    }
```